# Google Swiffy and touch events on mobile. specifically : touchstart > e.preventDefault

Tags: google-swiffy

swiffy conversion seems to hit an immediate roadblock with elements which have dragging behaviour. the problem is the window itself which drags / moves about when  ' touchmove_ing '. this is normally overcome by applying the preventDefault business to the document. but on the swiffy object / svg doc. . . cannot seem to apply this fix so the actual elements themselves can perform their dragging. anyone have any thoughts / ideas as to how to successfully prevent this ?

Comment: facing same issue. have u found a solution yet?

Comment: nah i haven't sorry. i trawl the web at regular intervals ( and the swiffy release notes ) to see if there's possibly any new light to shed on the problem. . . no such luck damn frustrating

Comment: yes let me know! I still miss as3 and really hope i can achieve some webapps through swiffy :D